# Do Ruby subprocesses properly sync STDOUT amongst themselves?

Tags: ruby, multiprocessing

I query the database for a collection of items to process, then split the collection into batches, and fork to process each batch separately. Similar to a fork/join.

Basically, this is what it looks like:

```
STDOUT.puts {"started_at": Time.now.utc}.to_json
batch = DB[:items].all # batch will contain from 10k to 50k items
batch.each_slice(5_000) do |group|
  fork do
    group.each do |item|
      rval = {...}
      STDOUT.puts rval.to_json
    end
  end
end

results = Process.waitall
STDOUT.puts {"done": true, "finished_at": Time.now.utc}.to_json
```

The output of each subprocess is a single JSON record, from a few hundred bytes to 600 MiB of data, all on a single line.

Is it possible that two subprocesses could clobber each other's output?